# Difference between Bag of words and Vector space model

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, vector-fields

I am searching for the intuitive difference between Bag-of-words and vector space model? Is there any relationship exists between bag-of-words and vector space model. I tried searching but couldn't find satisfactory answer.
[Bag of words vs vector space model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/bag-of-words-vs-vector-space-model) has also been asked but not answered in a satifactory way.

Answer (score 2):

I find existing answer very misleading.

The **Word vector** (aka **word embedding**) is concept coming from probabilistic language models (see [1]). It describes contextual similarity between the words in the language model and came into existence several decades after the **VSM** was proposed and successfully applied for text categorization, document summarization and information retrieval.

In the Vector Space Model (see [2]), it is **not word/term** being represented **as vector** in a n-dimensional space but **document**. The VSM is constructed to have **separate dimension** for each distinct unigram word/**term**, existing in collection of terms aggregated from all BOWs in the document collection. In other words, in the VSM: distinct **terms** became **dimensions**, not word vectors. **Documents** are vectors in the VSM, located at associated term weights by each corresponding dimension.

Bag-of-words (BOW), as approach of document representation in IR, does not allow multiple instances of same word - but represents an unordered list of distinct words, associated with their frequencies in the document (see [3]).

[1] Y. Bengio, R. Ducharme, P. Vincent, C. Janvin, A Neural Probabilistic Language Model, J. Mach. Learn. Res. 3 (2003) 1137–1155. doi:10.1162/153244303322533223.

[2] G. Salton, A. Wong, C. Yang  S., A vector space model for automatic indexing, Commun. ACM. 18 (1975) 613–620. doi:10.1145/361219.361220.

[3] G. SALTON, C.S. YANG, ON THE SPECIFICATION OF TERM VALUES IN AUTOMATIC INDEXING, J. Doc. 29 (1973) 351–372. doi:10.1108/eb026562.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the word "bag" means multiset, i.e., it allows multiple instances for each word. Thus:

- **Bag of words** indicates the count of each word in the document. This simple model is used, for example, in naive Bayes
- **Word vector** generalizes the idea of bag of words assigning a ranking to each word in the document. Often the occurrence count, but it can also be another ranking, such as the TF-IDF

Note that each row in a Document Term Matrix (DTM) corresponds to a word vector.